# Sinch App-to-App call but no sound

Tags: android, firewall, sinch

I've encountered a problem using Sinch App-to-App calling SDK.

When a client device is behind an enterprise firewall and the other device is outside of the firewall, calls can be established but there is no sound.

I think the problem is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102255/what-firewall-ports-do-i-need-to-open-to-allow-sinch-and-webrtc-to-work).
But it's hard to ask all users to open these ports of their firewalls.
Is there any way to detect the problem? At least I can show a warning message to users.
Or can I retry to make calls with other port?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What firewall ports do I need to open to allow Sinch and WebRTC to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102255/what-firewall-ports-do-i-need-to-open-to-allow-sinch-and-webrtc-to-work)

Comment: its the same problem, the ports need to be open and they are usually configured to be opened when a client tries to communicate thru them. if they are blocked it may be because the company doesnt want UDP traffic.

Comment: @cjensen
 Is it possible to know the UDP traffic is blocked in **CallListener** events? So that I can show a warning message to users and finish the CallScreenActivity

Comment: sorry not at the moment